# Pass parameters through listform.aspx?

Tags: rest, web-services, list-form

I have a list where the user needs the id of the current item to look up some other elements. But as we know the item id is not available until the items is created.

So I'm using REST to create a list item and then open the edit form. The item creation is working well and in my done handler I have this

```
$.ajax(obj)
    .done(function(data,status,xhr){
        var results = data.d;

        window.location.href =_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl+"/_layouts/15/listform.aspx" +
                              "?PageType=6" +
                              "&ListId={E1D61219-D33F-4E02-B94C-97D80BFD40CF}"+
                              "&ID="+data.d.Id +
                              "&firstedit=true"
    })
```

the `listform.aspx` opens the correct edit form for the created item. I was hoping that any extra parameters not known by listform.aspx would be passed through to the opened form, but it doesn't pass through my `firstedit` parameter.

Is there some way to pass custom parameters through `listform.aspx` to the form it opens?

**Edit**

We only have site admin permissions, so can only use client side solutions or things that are already available in the ui/api.

Comment: did you try using a more traditional url? `/sites/lists/listname/forms/editform.aspx?firstedit=true&ID="+data.d.Id`

Comment: We are using custom forms and they may have different names that change over time. My understanding was that listform.aspx was safest most flexible way to go.

Comment: That is just as static as what you are doing, the list name (Title) may change, but the underlying URL won't (like the GUID).

Comment: I'm confused by what you are saying. The /_layouts/15/listform.aspx url will never change and will always redirect me to the current edit form for that list regardless of what that form is called. But the URL you've listed might change to /forms/MySuperShinyEditForm.aspx or /forms/WellThisIsEvenBetterEditForm.aspx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For folks who don't read the comments, here is the answer that I came up with through Kai's help.

He checked out the `listform.aspx` code and confirmed that it trims any extra parameters passed to the url, so there isn't a way to pass any extra parameters through.

We found the following REST endpoints that perform the same function.

```
<site>/_api/web/lists('guid')/DefaultEditFormUrl
<site>/_api/web/lists('guid')/contenttypes('ctid')/editFormU‌​rl thank you for the help.
```

The first returns the url for the list's default edit form and the second returns the edit form for an item of a specific content type. Earlier I wasn't having any luck finding them because I had been looking under the `/_api/web/lists/forms` enpoints, which seems like where those should be, but evidently not!

So I can just make a call (I'm using jQuery to handle the ajax) like this.

```
return $.ajax({
  url:<site>/_api/web/lists('<guid>')/contenttypes('<ctid>')/editFormU‌​rl,
  type:"GET",
  headers:{
        "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        "X-RequestDigest'":$("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val();
    }
})
.done(function(data,status,xhr){
   var formUrl = data.d.EditFormUrl;
   window.location.href = location.origin+"/"+formUrl+"?ID="+listItemId+"&firstedit=true";
})
```

I already have the listItemId from create the item via REST in some previous code.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the code (using Reflector or ILSpy) for `listform.aspx`, you will see that corresponding class `ListFormRedirect` has following code when building redirect url (it also truncates all extra query parameters, that's why your approach doesn't work):

```
SPForm sPForm = sPList.Forms[this.m_FormType];
if (sPForm != null)
{
    stringBuilder.Append(base.Web.GetServerRelativeUrlFromUrl(sPForm.Url));
}
```

You can write a code to do exactly the same.
Some basic code for showing list form urls with CSOM:

```
var list = ctx.Web.GetListByUrl("Lists/tests list");
ctx.Load(list);
ctx.Load(list.Forms);
ctx.ExecuteQuery();

foreach (Form form in list.Forms)
{
    Console.WriteLine(form.FormType);
    Console.WriteLine(form.ServerRelativeUrl);
}
```

Output:

```
DisplayForm
/sites/dev/Lists/tests list/DispForm.aspx
EditForm
/sites/dev/Lists/tests list/EditForm.aspx
NewForm
/sites/dev/Lists/tests list/NewForm.aspx
```

Comment: Thank you for that. I should have mentioned that we don't have access to the aspx files, so I won't be able to do this, but as you mention it truncates all other paramters. Can you direct me to any documentation for this? For example which parameters will it take? I've seen the ones I've used and also RootFolder and ContentTypeId. Is there no way to pass Source?

Comment: You don't need any aspx files for that. This is client object model (.net), but this is also definitely available for javascript. What you really need is to get list form url (edit form your requirement), then append `?firstedit=true&ID=‌​"+data.d.Id`, ie `/sites/dev/Lists/tests list/DispForm.aspx?firstedit=true&ID=‌​"+data.d.Id`. Let me add JS sample

Comment: I just tried it with REST <site>_api/web/lists('guid')/forms?$filter=FormType eq 6 and I got back two entries -- one for the default EditForm and another for our custom form. By default I get Id, ServerRelativeUrl and FormType. I don't see anything that tells me which one is the correct one. Any ideas on that?

Comment: I found <site>/_api/web/lists('guid')/DefaultEditFormUrl, but that returns the built in EditForm. So I wonder what listform.aspx is returning?

Comment: Found it! <sites>/api/web/lists('guid')/contenttypes('ctid')/editFormUrl thank you for the help.

Comment: If content type option provided, it queries content type and building url using content type's `EditFormUrl` (or display etc..). I think this is your case - one edit form url is coming from content type

Comment: Right, you are a bit faster than me :)

Comment: The ability to flail through dozens of wrong solutions is one of my super-powers! Thank you so much for the help.